# PullToRefresh: добавить item по мере прокрутки

Tags: android, java

у меня вопрос по `pull to refresh`. Изначально в листвью отображается 5 итемов (примерно до появления скроллинга). Затем, если проскролить вниз, добавляются все итемы. Мне же нужно, чтобы итемы добавлялись не сразу все, а по мере прокрутки (по одному-два итема). Кто-нибудь работал с этой библиотекой? 
Библиотеку брал отсюда [`Android-PullToRefresh`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/226846/android-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: а разве в библиотеке которою использовал я нет такой возможности?

Comment: @odradek, pull_to_refresh под ваши требования не подходит